# Need some help on mysql query joining 2 tables by id

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've already looked through similarly titled threads, but could not make the following sql query to output results.

```
SELECT p.user_id, po.rating_entry_id, po.count_entries 
FROM $table1_name po 
INNER JOIN $table2_name p 
  ON po.$table1_name.post_id=p.$table2_name.post_id
```

Below are the actual tables. Database connections is through WP class.

```
global $wpdb;
  $table1_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mrp_rating_result";
  $table2_name = $wpdb->prefix . "mrp_rating_item_entry";
```

```
CREATE TABLE `testtbl_mrp_rating_item_entry` (
  `rating_item_entry_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rating_form_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entry_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'approved',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

CREATE TABLE `testtbl_mrp_rating_result` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rating_form_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_entry_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filters_hash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `star_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `adjusted_star_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `score_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `adjusted_score_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `percentage_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `adjusted_percentage_result` float(6,3) NOT NULL,
  `total_max_option_value` bigint(3) NOT NULL,
  `count_entries` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_totals` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_dt` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Please suggest possible corrections.

Comment: Why in your select are you prefixing your table names with $?  oh.. I get it now.  yeah you can't write it that way if you want Dynamic SQL you need to execute the SQL String statement.  Why are you using variables for table names?  If you put the actual table name(s) in the Select does it work?

Comment: Hello, using variables during db connector syntax, and aside this specific join tables sql queries are working and outputing.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you provide an example of the fully rendered SQL statement, a sample of the results you are expecting, and the results you are getting instead?

Comment: With a print_r funtion getting empty --Array ( ) --

Comment: Are you 100% positive you have the same post_ID in both tables?  Switch it to a full outer join do you get records? and or data in both tables?  Full outer join would ensure it's not a no id match problem...

Comment: To confirm post_ids are pairing.

Comment: ``` $specialuserid = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT p.user_id, po.rating_entry_id, po.count_entries FROM $table1_name po INNER JOIN $table2_name p ON po.$table1_name.post_id=p.$table2_name.post_id" );                         $specialuserid = array();
  foreach ($specialuserid as $row){
  $specialuserid[] = $row->post_id;
  print_r($specialuserid);
}``` Array ( )